# How can I automatically highlight a field with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to have a field it automatically underline as the user is typing. The line follows the characters, and when the person leaves the field, I want the livery to fill it all up. Because it means that the user has finished filling that field.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I do not have code because I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, Your question is not clear. But, I think you want to make user typing status. So let's do this. I use jQuery for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){

 if($("#target").val()!=""){
  $('span').show();
  }else{
     $('span').hide();
  }},1000);  
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="write" id="target">
<span style="display:none;">Typing</span>
```